# Double loop in Ansible, how to deal with it?

Tags: docker, ansible

I have this construction:

```
- name: Run validation query on db localy
  shell: >
    docker exec postgres.1.$(docker service ps -f "name=postgres.1" postgres -q) bash -c 'psql -v --username "{{ pg_connection_speruser }}" --dbname "{{ pg_db }}" -c "select 1"'
  register: validation_query
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ groups.postgres_server }}"
  until: validation_query.stderr == ''
  retries: 6
  delay: 10
  ignore_errors: false
  changed_when: false
```

What i need is to do:

```
- name: Run validation query on db localy
  shell: >
    docker exec postgres.{{ item }}.$(docker service ps -f "name=postgres.{{ item }}" postgres -q) bash -c 'psql -v --username "{{ pg_connection_speruser }}" --dbname "{{ pg_db }}" -c "select 1"'
  register: validation_query
  with_sequence: start=1 end="{{ pg_docker_service_replicas }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ groups.postgres_server }}"
  until: validation_query.stderr == ''
  retries: 6
  delay: 10
  ignore_errors: false
  changed_when: false
```

But of course, there is a problem with double loop with_sequence and with_items.

Is possible to do it in another way? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible double loop in hostvars](https://serverfault.com/questions/839996/ansible-double-loop-in-hostvars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `with_nested` and `lookup`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    max_num: 3
    delegates:
      - host1
      - host2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "delegate={{ item[0] }} seq={{ item [1] }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ delegates }}"
        - "{{ lookup('sequence','start=1 end='+max_num|string,wantlist=True) }}"
```

This will generate nested loop: outer one – over each item in `delegates` list (accessible via `item[0]`), inner one – over sequence `1-max_num`.

Comment: This will not work,  

with_nested:
        - "{{ delegates }}" returns server names per characters, so it will return h, then o, then s, and so on. 

Can i use lookup and wantlist=True for this?

Comment: This does work, believe me. I use ansible 2.2, just in case. Make sure that you feed a **list of two lists** to `with_nested` as I do in my example.

Comment: {{ groups.postgres_server }} is fed from postgres_server group from inventory